# What is the Android equivalent to iOS / iPhone's UICatalog sample app?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, user-interface

I'm looking for an app that demos all of Android UI elements.  Similar to the following:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are asking for Api demos, follow this link
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

And you can find Api Demos application in your android emulator too.

And the source code to them are shipped with the platforms itself. You can see the source in the

> android sdk folder-> Platforms->Android x.x->Samples